# WCF RIA Services waiting on a Single thread?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Can someone explain me why this is happening?

1. Silverlight 4 application using WCF Ria Services
2. SL app calls `StartLongOperation` `[Invoke]` operation.
   Due to synchronization issues with external components there is a `Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000)` in  the server-side code.
3. SL app calls `GetStatus` (standard query) operation.
   These calls appear to be blocked server-side and are waiting for the `StartLongOperation` to complete. Why??

I was assuming that serverside, the `StartLongOperation` runs an a worker thread and each call to `GetStatus` would run on a seperate worker thread. Client-side the calls are async so SL fires off the  `StartLongOperation` and then continues to poll the `GetStatus`. But the `GetStatusCompleted` doesn't get fired until the `StartLongOperation` has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all Silverlight network communication happens on the UI thread, only one WCF call can happen at a time. Meaning your StartLongOperation has to complete, and then the client will start the GetStatus call. If you want to test this behavior, fire up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). You will find that Silverlight will not send an HTTP request to the GetStatus method until it first gets a StartLongOperation response from the server.

So the problem isn't server-side. It's a limitation of Silverlight.

Comment: Odd, as when the SL app starts we do several GetXXX calls and those all happen concurrently (checked via Fiddler and the Timeline view)

Comment: Thanks for the tip though, I think another call might be the blocking factor, could be database locking problems...

Comment: Did you use Fiddler to test the StartLongOperation and GetStatus WCF calls? Or just the various GetXXX calls? Another question: Are you using the same WCF client object to make your GetXXX calls, or are you newing up a new object for each call?